# Accessing API with for-loop randomly has encoding error, which breaks loop in R

Tags: r, encoding

I'm trying to access an API from [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/) to download some citizen science data. I'm using the package `rinat` to get this done ([see vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rinat/rinat.pdf)). The loop below is, essentially, pulling all observations for one species, in one state, in one year iteratively on a per-month basis, then summing the number of observations for that year (input parameters subset from my actual script for convenience).

```
require(rinat)

state_ids <- c(18, 14)
bird_ids <- c(14886,1409)

months <- c(1:12)

final_nums <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(state_ids)){
  total_count <- vector()
  
  for(j in 1:length(months)){
    
  monthly <- get_inat_obs(place_id=state_ids[i],
                          taxon_id=bird_ids[i],
                          year=2019,
                          month = months[j])
  
  total_count <- append(total, length(monthly$scientific_name))
  
  print(paste("done with month", months[j], "in state", state_ids[i]))
  }
  
  final_nums <- append(final_nums, sum(total_count))
  print(paste("done with state", state_ids[i]))
}
```

Occasionally, and seemingly randomly, I get the following error:

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in if (!x$headers$`content-type` == "text/csv; charset=utf-8") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

This ends up breaking the loop or makes the loop run without actually pulling any real data. Is this an issue with my script, or the API, or something else? I've tried manually supplying encoding information to the `get_inat_obs()` function, but it doesn't accept that as an argument. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, is `total` in the append statement supposed to be `total_count`?

Comment: Also, Are you getting an error with this specific example? because I was not able to reproduce this error using the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is an error in your script. The issue is with the api most likely.

the error `argument is of length zero` is a common error when you try to make a comparison that has no length. For example:

```
if(logical(0) == "TEST") print("WORKED!!")
#Error in if (logical(0) == "TEST") print("WORKED!!") : 
#  argument is of length zero
```

I did some a few `grep`s on their source code to see where this `if` statement is and it seems to be within `inat_handle` line 211 in `get_inate_obs.R`
This would suggest that the authors did not expect for

```
!x$headers$`content-type` == 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'
```

to evaluate to `logical(0)`, but more specifically

```
x$headers$`content-type`
```

to be `NULL`.

I would suggest making a bug report on their GitHub and recommend they change the specified line to:

```
if(is.null(x$headers$`content-type`) || !x$headers$`content-type` == 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'){
```

Suggesting a bug is usually more well received if you have a reproducible example.

Also, you could totally make this change yourself locally by cloning out the git repository, editing the file, rebuild the package, and then confirm if you no longer get an error in your code.